# Sending event to GA4 occasionally fails with TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, service-worker

Currently, I am sending custom GA events on any push notification action from the service worker. To send the events I used the endpoint and parameters from official [GA4 documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=gtag#send_an_event).

Since I cannot see the browser terminal to see the error, in the code for GA endpoint failures I log an error to my database. I receive a majority of the GA events (95%), but some of them fail and I get either `TypeError: Load failed` or `TypeError: Failed to fetch` logged to my database.

I personally cannot replicate the issue myself. All events triggered by me are sent successfully, but for some website users it fails. I tried checking if I could find a common theme based on their devices or browsers, but it seems to be random since it happens on *Samsung Internet*, *Mobile Safari*, *Chrome Mobile* and other browsers.

My service worker:

```
// ...

// Triggered when push notification is closed
self.addEventListener('notificationclose', event => {
  event.waitUntil(trackEvent('webpush_action', { action: 'Closed' }));
});

async function trackEvent(name, params) {
  // ...

  const subscription = await self.registration.pushManager.getSubscription();

  if (!subscription) {
    throw new Error('No subscription currently available.');
  }

  try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=${measurementId}&api_secret=${apiSecret}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        client_id: subscription.endpoint,
        events: [{ name, params }]
      })
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(await response.text());
    }

    console.info('[Service Worker] Analytics event sent:', name);
  } catch (error) {
    const message = `[Service Worker] Unable to send the analytics event: ${error}`;
    console.warn(message);
    await logAnError(message); // just to log an error to my database for debugging purposes
  }
}
```

I tried manually replicating the issue by executing `fetch` to send the events from the browser console with either incorrect `api_secret`, `client_id` or events data values, but I could not get the error. The call always returns 204.